# IE11 Compatibility Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie-compatibility-mode

I have a legacy website which works only in IE9 and below and for IE 10 the compatibility mode worked fine.

Now in IE11 to get to the compatibility mode I tried F12-> Emulation and in the "Document mode"  option and chose the option 8 but the website totally collapses.

But the website works perfectly on IE-8 but when the same site in IE-11 and the Document mode is 8 why does the website collapse.

Or is there any other way to set compatibility mode.

I even tried placing the meta tag in head section for the jsp pages but still did not work.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

And how to run the website in Quirks Mode in IE11, the selection of Quirks Mode in older browsers was clear, but I'm not able to find the Quirks Mode option in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

That nice little icon used to change compatibility mode no longer available in ie - 11
but you still can choose compatibility mode by different ways.

Read this nice blog post

http://blog.algonquinstudios.com/2014/05/06/compatibility-view-in-ie11/